# why infinite loop doesn't apply when iterating backwards with for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop

I am learning javascript and I have two questions hope you can help :)
I have two for loops iterating backwards

- first example :

```
for (var i = 10; i--;) {
  console.log(i, "backward");
}
// starts at 9 and stops at 0
// without breaking condition
```

- second example :

```
for (var i = 10; i >= 0; i--) {
  console.log(i, "backward");
}
// starts at 10 and stops at 0
// with breaking condition that i >= 0
```

1. why in the **first example** we don't need to set a breaking point for the loop ? like `i > 0` ? is it because 0 is false anyway ? so when it reaches 0 it automatically breaks ? and it won't keep iterating like 0, -1, -2, -3, ....etc ?
2. why in the **second example** the iterating starts at 10 while in the **first example** it starts at 9 ?

thanks for your support :D
Cheers

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for shows that all parameters are `optional` and explains what happens if they're omitted.

Answer (score 2):

1. `i--` *is* the breaking point. A post-decrement expression subtracts 1 from the variable and returns the previous value. So when `i` is `0`, the value of `i--` is `0`, which is falsey, and the loop stops.
2. Because in the first example we're decrementing `i` during the repeat condition, which runs *before* the body, so the first iteration already has it decremented to `9`. In the second example we're decrementing `i` in the update expression, which runs *after* the body, so it still has the initial value `10` during the body of the first iteration.

To understand what a `for` loop is doing, expand it into the analogous `while` loop.

```
for(initialize; condition; update) {
    body
}
```

is roughly equivalent to

```
initialize;
while (condition) {
    body;
    update;
}
```

Comment: Nicely explained.